# Is there a way to make Android Studio automatically save project to Dropbox or similar?

Tags: android-studio

I'm not sure if SO is the right place to ask this, but I found nothing by googling.

Is there a way to make Android Studio automatically backup your project to Dropbox, for example if you Save project or if you exit Android Studio. The reason I wanna do this is because my laptop needed a windows reinstall recently, so to avoid losing my projects, I would like to do something like mentioned above. Thank you.

Comment: Why not use an actual version control system instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install the [Dropbox Desktop App](https://www.dropbox.com/install), you could place your Android Studio project files in the Dropbox folder that automatically syncs with your online Dropbox storage.

Once you install the Desktop Application, when you open your file browser, you'll see Dropbox as a storage location:

[image: Dropbox File Browser]

Anything you store in that location will be automatically uploaded and synced with your online Dropbox storage.

So if you put your project in that Dropbox location, it will automatically be uploaded to Dropbox anytime you save or change files.

You can also do the same thing with the [Google Drive Desktop App](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) if you'd rather go with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the comment for the answer...

While that works (and I been doing it for a while now), problem is that if I change just one file, there will be a lot of files uploaded, and that even if I start "gradle clean" before I reactive dropbox sync (I disable sync while I am developing, so that not all updates go up to the server).

Interesting would be to just share the source files and not all other files... Yes I know you would loose "Local history" and you have to download all new dependencies, when you switch the computer (I share my project between 2-3 computers), but still you would keep the important files that way. So having AS upload just interesting files would be much better solution, and  if AS had option to zip all important files, that would work much better.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to syncing selective files to cloud is using hard links.

1. Cut your **/root_app_folder/app/src/main/** folder and paste it inside a folder that syncs with the cloud.
2. Create a hard symbolic link using cmd on Windows pointing to your new directory (**mklink /J "\root_app_folder\app\src\main"
   "\sync_folder\main"**)

See more about [creating hard link on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/). Please leave a comment if someone know a way for Mac/Linux.